# C++: CryptEncrypt Unable to encrypt large file

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption

Having problem encrypting large file using Windows API CryptEncrypt. Currently only able to encrypt small text file.
I am not sure how to run the CryptEncrypt as mentioned in MSDN.

Could anyone give me some assists?

```
bool fEOF = FALSE;

do {
    if (!ReadFile(hSourceFile, pbBuffer, dwBlockLen, &dwCount, NULL)) {
        handleError("Error reading source.\n", GetLastError());
        goto Exit_encryptFile;
    }

    if (dwCount < dwBlockLen) {
        fEOF = TRUE;
    }

    //Encrypt File

    if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, fEOF, 0, pbBuffer, &dwCount, dwBufferLen)) {
        handleError("Error during CryptEncrypt.\n", GetLastError());
        wchar_t err[256];
        memset(err, 0, 256);
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);
        int msgboxID = MessageBoxW(NULL,
            err,
            (LPCWSTR)L"☠",
            MB_OK);
        goto Exit_encryptFile;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement. See also [ask] questions

Comment: Which line causes this error? Also [your know the drill...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtxUk.jpg).

Comment: Oh no so sorry. I do not use forum much so i do not know the rules.

Comment: @VTT CryptEncrypt is throwing **bad data** error. Think it's caused by large file being thrown into the API

Comment: @VTT do you have any hint on how to do it? I will try this out once I reach home

Comment: @VTT _When a block cipher is used, this data length must be a multiple of the block size unless this is the final section of data to be encrypted and the Final parameter is TRUE._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved this issue by increasing the block size to 256 and it start encrypting without any error.
Shall see if i can decrypt this after i code it.